# yaml repeated node that is a key

Tags: yaml

I have a hierarchy of categories in yaml. There are no values, only keys. How can I make a repeated node? For example, I want `Apps` in both the `Entertainment` category and the `Tech` category. Usually repeated nodes are noted as values, as in the following example:

```
hr:
  - Mark McGwire
  # Following node labeled SS
  - &SS Sammy Sosa
rbi:
  - *SS # Subsequent occurrence
  - Ken Griffey
```

But in my case I have only keys, not values. I tried the following, but when I loaded it into python using `pyyaml` I got a dictionary containing `App: None` for the reference to `App`.

```
Entertainment:
    Music:
        Country:
        Hip hop:
        Pop:
        Rock:
        Alternative:
    &Apps Apps:
        Games:
        Productivity:
        Travel:
        Finance:
        Lifestyle:
Goods:
    Tech:
        Visual:
            Projectors:
            TVs:
        Phones:
            Smart phones:
            Feature phones:
        *Apps:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK anchors can be applied to nodes (i.e. data, sequences, and mappings), but not necessarily to a key within a node. So the `Apps` key cannot be anchored, but the mapping that `Apps` contains is fair game. This works for me:

```
Entertainment:
    Music:
        Country:
        Western:
    Apps: &AppsKeys
        Games:
        Travel:
Goods:
    Tech:
        Visual:
        Phones:
        Apps: *AppsKeys
```

I guess using the `Apps` keyword is slightly redundant. There may also be some way to apply an anchor to an individual key that I don't know about. But my guess is that it's not possible, since it doesn't represent a fundamental unit (aka node).