# Make DEPLOY job automatic for release branches and manual for others with GitLab CI

Tags: deployment, yaml, gitlab-ci

The next solution should work.

```
deploy_release:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
  - linux
  only: 
  - master
  - stable
  retry: 2
  script:
  - do_action 1
  - do_action 2
  - git push artifacts

deploy_manual:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
  - linux
  except: 
  - master
  - stable
  when: manual
  retry: 2
  script:
  - do_action 1
  - do_action 2
  - git push artifacts
```

But it has one ☝️ **significant** lack – `script:` is repeated 2 times.

#### I think it would be a good idea to write something like:

```
.deploy_base:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
  - linux
  retry: 2
  script:
  - do_action 1
  - do_action 2
  - git push artifacts

deploy_release:
  include: .deploy_base
  only: 
  - master
  - stable

deploy_manual:
  include: .deploy_base
  except: 
  - master
  - stable
  when: manual
```

*But I doubt this will work.* **Is it possible to do something similar in YAML?**

---

The other straight-forward idea is to

#### move `script:` to separate file `deploy_script.sh`

and finish the problem in the bud.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#anchors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this Q&A [yaml repeated node that is a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627870/yaml-repeated-node-that-is-a-key)

### The solution is:

```
.deploy_base:  &deploy_base
  stage: deploy
  tags:
  - linux
  retry: 2
  script:  &deploy_script
  - do_action 1
  - do_action 2
  - git push artifacts

deploy_release:
  only:  &deploy_release_only
  - master
  - stable
  script: *deploy_script

deploy_manual:
  except: *deploy_release_only
  when: manual
  script: *deploy_script
```

## And even better:

#### inherit `.deploy_base`:

```
.deploy_base: &deploy_base
  stage: deploy
  tags:
  - DlpcsCore
  - linux
  retry: 2
  variables:
    URL: 'git@gitlab.com:Yahoo/HeavenShine-bin.git'
  script: &deploy_script
  - do_act_1
  - do_action_2

deploy_release:
  << : *deploy_base
  only: &deploy_release_only
  - master
  - stable
  - CI
  #- /^master[-_].+$/
  #- /^(.+)[+]bin$/

deploy_manual:
  << : *deploy_base
  except: *deploy_release_only
  when: manual
```

To get know more search for *YAML merge*

Answer (score 5):

Here it is 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#extends

## [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#extends)

> Introduced in GitLab 11.3

`extends` defines an entry name that a job, that uses extends is going to inherit from.
`extends` in an alternative to using YAML anchors that is a little more flexible and readable.

```
.tests:
  only:
    refs:
      - branches

rspec:
  extends: .tests
  script: rake rspec
  stage: test
  only:
    variables:
      - $RSPEC
```

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab now support this via `rules` directive: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules-clauses